# Concatinate json output response

Tags: php, json

I am using a AJAX /php form .

```
if (strlen($name) < 4) { // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => '<br /> - ' . _t('"Naam" field contains invalid value')));
    die($output);
}
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { //email validation
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => '<br /> - ' . _t('"E-mail" field contains invalid value')));
    die($output);
}
if (strlen($subject) < 3) { //check emtpy message
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => '<br /> - ' . _t('"Onderwerp" field contains invalid value')));
    die($output);
}
if (strlen($message) < 3) { //check emtpy message
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => '<br /> - ' . _t('"Vraag" field contains invalid value')));
    die($output);
}
```

The AJAX script :

```
$.post('contact_form', post_data, function (response) {
    if (response.type == 'error') { //load json data from server and output message     
        output = '<div class="error">' + response.text + '</div>';
    } else {
        output = '<div class="success">' + response.text + '</div>';
        //reset values in all input fields
        $("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").val('');
        $("#contact_form #contact_body").slideUp(); //hide form after success
    }
    $("#contact_form #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
}, 'json');
```

The above code it valides form and output if is there any error.
My issue is that i receive 1 error only. How can i receive all the errors in a json object ?

Comment: You are overwriting `$output` in every check. Use array instead and a final `json_encode`

Answer (score 0):

Somehting like this will give all errors. It pushes every error into an array and returns the whole array instead of exiting after one error

```
$output = array();

if (strlen($name) < 4) { // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
    $output[] = array('type' => 'error', 'text' => '<br /> - ' . _t('"Naam" field contains invalid value'));
}
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { //email validation
    $output = array('type' => 'error', 'text' => '<br /> - ' . _t('"E-mail" field contains invalid value'));
}
if (strlen($subject) < 3) { //check emtpy message
    $output[] = (array('type' => 'error', 'text' => '<br /> - ' . _t('"Onderwerp" field contains invalid value'));
}
if (strlen($message) < 3) { //check emtpy message
    $output[] = array('type' => 'error', 'text' => '<br /> - ' . _t('"Vraag" field contains invalid value'));
}

if (count($output)) die(json_encode($output));
```

You will also have to iterate through these errors and show them all in your JS